# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION ... on line 4

Tags: php

Ok, I know this must just be some comma or bracket missing but for the life of me I don't see it.  I am new to PHP so maybe it is something else.  I have a function working in another script and it's just function name($variables){ code }  So why isn't that working here???

Thank you for finding my stupid mistake - if it is one.

display.php

```
<?php
  require('database.php');
  require('product_list.php');
  require('addprod.php');
  $productIDtx = $_POST['productIDtx'];
  $categoryIDtx = $_POST['categoryIDtx'];
  $productCodetx = $_POST['productCodetx'];
  $productNametx = $_POST['productNametx'];
  $listPricetx = $_POST['listPricetx'];
  $categoryNametx = $_POST['categoryNametx'];

  if(isset($_POST['tableName']))
   {
        $table = $_POST['tableName'];
   }
  else
   {
        echo("Must select a table.<br>");
   }
  if(isset($_POST['operation']))
   {
        $operation = $_POST['operation'];
   }
  else
   {
        echo("Must select an action.<br>");
        exit();
   }
 if($operation == 'addition')
        {
                if($table == 'products')
                {
                   include_once('addprod.php');
                   add_products($productIDtx, $categoryIDtx, $productCodetx, $productNametx, $listPricetx);
                }
        }

?>
```

---

addprod.php

```
<?php
  include('database.php')
  //**LINE 4 IS THE LINE BELOW**
  function add_products($productIDtx, $categoryIDtx, $productCodetx, $productNametx, $listPricetx, $categoryNametx)   // **THIS IS LINE 4**
        {
                global $db;
                if (empty($productIDtx) || empty($categoryIDtx) || empty($productCodetx) || empty($productNametx) || empty($listPricetx) )
                {
                        $error = "Invalid product data. Check all fields and try again.";
                        echo ($error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $query = "INSERT INTO products (productID, categoryID, productCode, productName, listPrice)
                                VALUES ('$productIDtx', '$categoryIDtx', '$productCodetx', '$productNametx', '$listPricetx')";
                                $insert = $db->exec($query);
                }

                if ($insert < 1)
                {
                        echo ("<p>No records added.  Make sure values are valid and productID is unique.</p>");
                         exit();
                }

                $theQuery = "SELECT * FROM products order by productID";
                $rSet = $db -> query($theQuery);
                $list = "";
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <header><title>Products</title></header>
        <body>
                <?php require('menu.html');?>
                <table border="1">
                        <?php
                            $list = "<tr><td>productID</td><td>categoryID</td><td>productCode</td><td>productName</td><td>List Price</td></tr>";
                            foreach($rSet AS $products)
                                {
                                   $list .= "<tr><td>".$products['productID']."</td>"
                                                ."<td>".$products['categoryID']."</td>"
                                                ."<td>".$products['productCode']."</td>"
                                                ."<td>".$products['productName']."</td>"
                                                ."<td>".$products['listPrice']."</td>"
                                            ."</tr>";
                                }
                            echo($list);
                        ?>
                 </table>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon on the line above it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addprod.php - line 2

```
 include('database.php')
```

Is missing the semicolon. Thats why the following function is unexpected

Comment: Thank you!  It was driving me nuts . . .that was it.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes One's just blind